# How to ensure consistent spacing in creating number pyramid in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, loops

my code is here. Entering a value of 1-9 does not break the spacing but when its 10 above it does.

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnsend'])) {
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $width = strlen($_POST['number']) + 1;
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $num; $row++) {
        echo "<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;'>";
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $row; $x++) {
            echo "<div style='width: {$width}ch; background: green;'>$row</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your (slightly modified and cleaned up) [code](https://3v4l.org/t5pBV) it [produces HTML](https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/oNpbeYv) the appears to render correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what you want the spacing to be given there may be any number of digits in a number or are there some limits/constraints?